# Why is "qui" used here, when it looks like it is replacing a direct object?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-interrogatifs

I saw this sentence on Duolingo:

> Vous pouvez inviter qui vous voulez.

I am wondering why "qui" is used here instead of "que".

If we "undo" the pronoun, it looks like "qui" here is replacing a direct object:

> Vous pouvez inviter [Marc]. Vous voulez [Marc].

(Similarly, I'll make up an example of another sentence where a relative pronoun replaces a direct object:

> Vous mangez [la pomme]. Vous prenez [la pomme].
>   -->
>   Vous mangez la pomme **que** vous prenez.

)

So, can someone show me where I'm mistaken? Why is "qui" used here instead of "que"?

Comment: In the first ssentence, to use "que", you should say "Vous pouvez inviter la personne que vous voulez". It is similar to the "who" in english. "You may invite **who** you wish", or "You may invite the person you wish"

Comment: @Random: oh, thank you for your example sentence, because that example sentence (with "la personne" written there) does follow exactly the constructions saw when learning about the relative pronouns "qui" and "que". My problem sentence "Vous pouvez inviter qui vous voulez" does not have this familiar construction, so this makes me wonder if I have not yet learned the construction being used here. Is "qui" here even a relative pronoun, or is it something else?

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to accept your English example, however, unless I understand the underlying grammar. I think there have been times when the English "who" needs to be translated with "que" (and the English "that" needs to be translated with "qui"), depending on if "who" and "that" is a pronoun replacing an object, or if it is replacing a subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both examples you present are not equivalent. Compare:

#### Case 1

> *Vous invitez **qui** vous voulez.*
>   You invite **who**(ever) you wish.
>
> ---
>
> *Vous mangez **ce que** vous voulez.*
>   You eat **what**(ever) you wish.

#### Case 2

> *Vous invitez **(celui) qui** vous plait.*
>   You invite **(the one) who** pleases you.
>
> ---
>
> *Vous mangez **ce qui** vous plait.*
>   You eat **what** pleases you.

#### Case 3

> *Vous venez avec l'ami **que** vous avez invité.*
>   You come with the friend (**that/whom**) you invited.
>
> ---
>
> *Vous mangez la pomme **que** vous avez prise.*
>   You eat the apple (**that/which**) you have taken.

#### Case 4

> *Je viens avec l'ami **qui** m'a répondu.*
>   I come with the friend **who** answered me.
>
> ---
>
> *Je regrette cette pomme **qui** m'a donné mal au ventre.*
>   I regret eating that apple **which** made my stomach hurt.

#### A bit of explanation

There are several type of [dependent/subordinate clauses in French](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/propositions-subordonnees.php). Here, both cases are **relative (dependent/subordinate) clauses** (*proposition subordonnée relative*) but with a nuance.

- In case 1, the dependent clause does not have any antecedent. In this case, you would use *qui* for people (or maybe pets) and *que* for anything else. Just think of **who (*qui*) vs. what(*que*)**.
- In case 2, the dependent clause still does not have any antecedent, but the relative pronoun is now the subject of the relative clause. In this case, we use *qui* each time. You can notice the *ce* or *celui*. *Ce* is indefinite for objects, *celui* (or *celle* in feminine, or *ceux/celles* at plural) can be used for objects as a definite form but are definite and indefinite for people.
- In case 3, the dependent clause begins with a pronoun which is not the subject of the clause. Here, we can see **we use *que* for living and non-living subjects.**
- In case 4, the dependent clause begins with a pronoun which *is* the subject of the clause. This time, **we use *qui* for living and non-living subjects.**

---

<sub>I am always unsure about when to use *who* or *whom*, so please warn me/edit if I made a mistake.</sub>

Comment: Showing me the 3 different cases was very helpful. Case 2 and 3 are familiar to me. When I was learning about relative pronouns "qui" and "que", they used the terminology of _antecedent_ and _subordinate clause_ ( = dependant clause, I'm guessing), so I understand your explanation about case 2 and 3. Case 1 is unfamiliar to me, so it gives me a starting point for using Google to learn about _dependant clauses that don't have an antecedent_. One question: is "que" or "qui" in Case 1 still called a "relative pronoun", or is it called some other grammar word?

Comment: Yes, I used _dependent clause_ for _subordinate clause_ since it was the translation I found and I was not sure. I will update since to use the most common terms. Yes, the pronoun is still a relative pronoun [according to Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_relative#Relative_sans_ant.C3.A9c.C3.A9dent_.28substantive.29).

Comment: I have been reading about relative pronouns where there is no expressed antecedent ("indefinite relative pronouns") [here](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/indefiniterelativepronouns.htm) and [here](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/pror2.html), and I am wondering about _Vous invitez qui vous voulez._. Should that instead be _Vous invitez **ce qui** vous voulez_? Or can _qui_ (not _ce qui_) actually be an indefinite relative pronoun, and if so, when is it used instead of _ce qui_?

Comment: @silph I missed that case. My case 1 was correct, but when the pronoun is subject you need something more. _Ce_ is indefinite for objects. For a definite version or for people, you will use _celui/celle/ceux/celles_. I added a case in my answer, I hope it remains clear.

Comment: your explanation is clear to me (other than my not knowing very precisely what the words "definite" and "indefinite" mean, but that's okay because i am sure i will learn about that when i read grammar sites more). Thanks you for adding in Case 2. it seems that i have not read the grammar sites as carefully as i should, because your explanation of case 1 vs case 2 does not sound familiar to me! your Case 1 and Case 2 elaboration definitely will help me research this grammar point further.

Answer (score -2):

**Vous pouvez inviter *qui* vous voulez.**
You could have also used **que** in this case, but here, it is a person who has to be replaced by a PRONOM RELATIF SIMPLE. So, instead of **que** which is used in case of things, we use **qui** because there is a person.

For clarification, I would like you to refer to the following example. It might help you in better comprehension of PRONOM RELATIF SIMPLE:

**La seule personne a qui je peux donner la confiance est mon frere cadet.**

**La seule chose qui me plait est une promenade au bord de la mer.**

Here,in the first sentence, we use QUI because we are replacing a person by the pronoun. However, in the second sentence, we use QUE because a thing (a long walk by the seashore) is being replaced here.

Comment: Que and qui both can replace a person or a thing it all depends wether that thing they are replacing is the subject/direct object  of the clause following them (dependent clause). See here's an example from my grammar book : _L'homme **que vous voyez** au fond de l'atelier est un des meilleurs artisans du pays_ = _The man you see in the back of the shop is one of the best craftsmen in the country._

Comment: However when qui replaces an indirect object (which has a preposition like: à for instance) qui can only refer to people
Ex : _C'est l'antiquaire **à qui** je pensais._ 

_He's the antiques dealer I was thinking about._



Also it depends wether it's a definite or indefinite thing or object they are replacing and in such case we would use indéfinite relative pronouns.